# For what purpose does it make sense to give a property setter method a return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, setter

In what context would it make sense to give a class property setter method a return value as shown in the following code snippet?

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    @property # getter method
    def full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    @full_name.setter # setter method
    def full_name(self, name):
        self.first_name, self.last_name = name.split()
        return 'When and how should I use this return value?'
```

Comment: None, really. The setter is meant to be invoked by an assignment statement, which doesn't have a value at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the setter *can* return a value, it is meant to be invoked in a context where that return value will be ignored. In something like

```
p = Person()
p.full_name = "John Doe"
```

the assignment will be performed by `Person.full_name.__set__(p, "John Doe")`. If you look in the descriptor how-to, there is a [section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) that demonstrates how the `property` class might be defined in pure Python. Most important for this question is how `__set__` will be implemented:

```
def __set__(self, obj, value):
    if self.fset is None:
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
    self.fset(obj, value)
```

`self.fset` is your setter. Note that its return value is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get the value use the `get` method.
If you want set the value use the programming language rules for `set` methods.

If you do this you are breaking the rules from POO encapsulation and the principle of single responsibility.

If you want to know more you can access this [wikipedia article about single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
Singles responsability is part of the SOLID design pattern and for POO one of the most used pattern. [Here is some reference](https://itnext.io/solid-principles-explanation-and-examples-715b975dcad4).

Comment: Neither `Person` nor `person` does have a `get` method. Could you give an example?

Comment: Well, that's because you're using python, the setter is being invoked in a implicit way. If you use a language like java, c#, php, C++, scala that getters are a common practice. Like in java its called a java bean (getters and setters).